# Mounted cloud drive(page blob) getting deleted

Tags: azure, cloud, blob, mount, drive

We have Azure PAAS service implementation.In that in each Instance we have 10 customer and each customer owns a mounted cloud drive(page blob) to store the some files.
This deployment is available for last one year in azure .

For last 2-3 weeks we observe that is 1-2 cloud drive(page blob) getting un-mounted from this instance .We got some error information from the System log of event viewer which is added and this error is also not consistent. Currently as work around we are rebooting  the Instance daily which we remount the vhd (pageblob) again.
Guest OS version-1.18
Azure SDK 1.7

Please let us know what is reason for this issue?

#### Error details

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        PlugPlayManager
Date:          4/22/2013 11:10:50 AM
Event ID:      12
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RD00155D477FE9
Description:
The device 'Msft VHD Disk SCSI Disk Device' (SCSI\Disk&Ven_Msft&Prod_VHD_Disk\1&26c3c0c&0&000002) disappeared from the system without first being prepared for removal.



Log Name:      System
Source:        WaDrivePrt
Date:          4/22/2013 11:10:49 AM
Event ID:      4
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RD00155D477FE9
Description:
'/lwe_2f44e5e3.vhd' failed to renew lease the specified XDisk.
```